# Cannot make my chart to work with data from mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, chart.js

I'm having trouble displaying a chart with data from mongoDB. I'm using Python, Flask, chartJS and mongoDB

Be patient, noob here....

My program:

PYTHON

```
import pymongo
from datetime import datetime
import html.parser as htmlparser
parser = htmlparser.HTMLParser()
# Mongo connection and Database initialization
myClient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
myDB = myClient['SST']
myCOL = myDB['SSTTemperature']

# Retrieve and iterate through the received document to get all the temperature data
recivedDocument = myCOL.find_one()
temperatureList = recivedDocument['StoragesList'][0]['TemperaturesList']
temperatureListLength = len(temperatureList)

# Save all the Temperature and date and time data in two separated arrays so that I can use them with chartJS
temperatureListData = []
timeListData = []

for everyTemperatureRead in range(temperatureListLength):
    temperatureListData.append(temperatureList[everyTemperatureRead]['Temperature']) # Now @tempListData ARRAY contains all the temperature data and ready to be use with chartJS
    timeListData.append(temperatureList[everyTemperatureRead]['Date']) # Now @timeListData ARRAY contains all the date and time data and ready to be use with chartJS

print(timeListData)
```

FLASK

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pymongo
import db

unitName = 'CBB-SST-R_1'

app = Flask (__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():

    return render_template("index.html" , SQLdataTime = db.timeListData, SQLdataTemp = db.temperatureListData  )

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Cmd output:

```
['2019-08-16T11:26:52Z', '2019-08-16T11:31:52Z', '2019-08-16T11:36:52Z',....]
```

Chrome developer tool:

```
[&#39;2019-08-16T11:26:52Z&#39;, &#39;2019-08-16T11:31:52Z&#39;, &#39;2019-08-16T11:36:52Z&#39;, &#39;2019-08-16T11:41:52Z&#39;, &#39;2019-08-16T11:46:52Z&#39;, .....]
```

Where did the extra `&#39;` come from?!

And how to solve this issue as my chart is blank?

Here's a screenshot to clarify my question:

[Image shows the output of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaRux.png)

Comment: Sorry but disagree strongly with some current SE practices, so I am giving you an advance on the **previous** close vote warning since it was less "warm and fuzzy" and actually frankly described the problem with your question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That means it's not really clear what you are asking because there is nothing in your question that demonstrates a problem. Yes the dates presented are in fact "strings", but that will actually be how you have them stored. Probably not the specific problem, but just how it it. But at no point do you clearly state if you are attempting to "plot" the "date values" or just use those as labels in your chart. The more likely problem is the array of `temperatureListData`, which is probably what is really not valid for a chart. Please read the links and clearly present the problem.

Comment: Thanks, @NeilLunn for your feedback and comments, will try to improve this post, just a NOOB here :)

Comment: to clear things more, yes my code is working but the plot is not working.
also, I found an extra char included in the data I do not know where it came from, and in the question, I found the extra CHARS changed to another symbol and i fixed that and yes you are right i want the dates to be used as a labels

Comment: `&#39` is the apostrophe, or single quote, which must be escaped in HTML. If you look at the command-line/terminal output, you'll see single quotes around the dates.

Comment: It looks like your date-times are actually pure strings, not datetime objects. This may have caused some conversion issues. There is also obviously some template stuff missing, so we don't know how the data is put into the template, but you should make sure it's properly json-ified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, for safety reasons Flask is escaping HTML, so I have to disable it by using (|safe) filter in my HTML file

for example:

```
{{ variableName | safe }}
```